# Почему задача на алгоритм Кадане не проходит некоторые тесты?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Я решаю задачи на code Wars. Просят найти максимальную сумму подмассива. Я почитал про алгоритм Кадене и, кажется, реализовал его. Моя функция проходит простые тесты, но не проходит некоторые из раздела `attempt`. Помогите понять в чем причина. Вот мой код:

```
let maxSequence = function(arr){
  // ...
  if (arr.length === 0) return 0;
  let result = arr[0];
  let sum = arr[0];
  
  
  for (let i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] === []) arr[i] = 0;
    sum = Math.max(arr[i], arr[i] + sum)
    result = Math.max(result, sum)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Он не проходит 17 тестов [отсюда](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54521e9ec8e60bc4de000d6c/train/javascript). Самым удивительным для меня является, то что реализация якобы не работает с отрецательными числами, хотя в простых тестах такие числа есть и алгоритм корректно находит сумму.

Comment: Ну про отрицательные там в условии сказано:  If the list is made up of only negative numbers, return 0 instead.

Comment: @AntonMironov это я исправил. Но все равно реализация не проходит некоторые тесты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправьте:

```
let result = 0;
let sum = 0;
```

Вот питоновский код, проходящий тесты:

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    summ = 0
    ans = 0
    for x in arr:
        summ = max (summ + x, 0)
        ans = max (ans, summ)
    return max(ans, 0)
```